# Last key of a Dictionary Excel VBA

Tags: excel, dictionary, key, last-modified, vba

How do I do if I just want the last (inserted) key of a dictionary in excel-VBA?

Will I have to iterate all over the dict every time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.Keys` property of a Dictionary is an `0` based array of the keys, in the order added.

To get the last added key, use

```
Dict.Keys(Dict.Count - 1)
```

Comment: Aha! I know why I got the wrong answer. +1 for correctness. :)